# Trigger onclick function of input that has been checked automatically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-click-event, jquery-triggerhandler

I have a form with some checkboxes which go like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id6" value="3" onclick="optionselect('day','3','id6','50')" />
```

Conditioned on another input I can have these checkboxes checked automatically but for some reason I can't trigger the "optionselect".

I've tried some of the following, but nothing works:

```
$("#id6").prop("checked", true).trigger("click");
$("#id6").prop("checked", true).triggerHandler("click");
$("#id6").prop("checked", true).click();
```

FYI, "optionselect" just does a bit of math in some other text inputs.

Comment: Because option select is not defined...

Comment: just trigger the click event like this $('#id6').trigger('click'); as checked would be checked when clicked.

Comment: Is working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/72ueN/ have you binded the handler in domready?

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem is that you should use `onchange` event in this case, not `click`. Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="id6" value="3" onchange="optionselect('day','3','id6','50')" />
```

and

```
$('#id6').prop('checked', true).change();
```

Basically `.click()` effectively unchecks checkbox after you checked it with `prop('checked', true)`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. The checkbox is checked but it doesn't trigger the function (it should add 3 to a certain number, which in this case is 0 and would turn to 3 if "optionselect" triggers).

Comment: Check console for errors. `onchange` handler is definitely called. It might be a problem with `optionselect` then. Show its code.

Comment: The only thing I get in the console is `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`. `optionselect` works fine if I click it normally.

Comment: Ok, so I guess we can only help if you provide a fiddle with the problem. Otherwise there is no way to find out.